# How to put information from input into a variable?

Tags: python

Lets say I have two input statements and want to input the information into another variable, and I want to put a "-" in between the two inputs.

```
first_name = input("FIRST NAME: ")
last_name = input("LAST NAME: ")

URL = "http://www.name.com/firstandlast/"
```

I want to put the information from first_name and last_name into the URL variable

I tried this but it didn't work and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
first_name = input("FIRST NAME: ")
last_name = input("LAST NAME: ")

URL = "http://www.name.com/firstandlast/" + first_name + "-" + last_name
```

Comment: use fstrings  `URL = f"http://www.name.com/firstandlast/{first_name}-{last_name}`. Your code should also work though. Could you post what your expected output is for a given first_name and last_name?

Comment: this code works for me.

Comment: Your code is fine